# stand alone php app

Tags: php

What is the best way to build a **non web browser** stand alone php app that works with some sort of database without requiring the user to install a database server.  Or am i just asking too much?

Comment: What are your platform requirements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're targeting Windows, try [WinBinder](http://winbinder.org). It allows you to develop native Windows applications using PHP.

It also supports SQLite, so you don't need a database server.

Comment: Looks like this may not be an ideal choice — they clearly label it as being "under development", but no new releases have been made since 2006.

Comment: True. The forums are still active and WinBinder's developer still posts; basically, the project needs either funding or additional developers to continue. Part of the problem is that most PHP developers don't know C, which makes it difficult for people interested in this type of thing to help with development. In any case, WinBinder appears to be mostly stable and supports PHP 5.1.x.

Answer (score 5):

Embed the SQLite database in your app, then configure PHP to talk to the SQLite database:

http://us.php.net/sqlite

Comment: It still wouldn't be a "standalone" as you'd need to install a PHP interpreter. And without a browser, it'll basically be a command-line script.

Comment: Good point.  Then again, the command-line script requires a command-line interpreter, which requires other components.  Pretty much won't be standalone unless he writes in ML against the machine, eh?  Then again, he did ask for a PHP solution, so I think we can assume a working PHP interpreter.  This solution will prevent the need for a database server and a web server, which was the question.  (He wants a command-line script as his result, re-read the question.)

Comment: He only asked that the user not have to install a DBMS not that the use not have to install PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at php compilers, you'll end up with a binary for people to run. It could be a desktop GUI application, or a "web server in a box" type of thing.

- [bamcompile](http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/)
- [phc](http://www.phpcompiler.org/)
- [roadsend](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?SMC=1&pageID=press)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you try [miniPHP](http://exvision.net/). It is basically an IDE around [Winbinder](http://winbinder.org/); it lets you concentrate on writing PHP while it takes care of details like compiling the application. You can create either GUI or command-line apps and it works just fine with both SQLite and MySQL. It has a preview mode and some debugging capabilities too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea: information can be stored in XML and thus usage of database can be avoided. That will work only for certain kind of purposes of course.

Comment: Without more data about what the submitter wants to do, this is probbaly the best idea.  Who knows, even a text file could work.  If the data is not large, or even fairly large, but not needing relations, flat files cab be great.

Answer (score 1):

As Oakcool has mentioned, check out PHP-GTK. It is a GUI development tool on the similar lines of MFC for C/C++.

PHP-GTK alongwith SQLite or a text file as others mentioned above should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this 3 links

PHP GTK`enter code here`
http://gtk.php.net/

FLEX
http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/?promoid=BPDEQ

AIR
http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

I think any those will help you, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with it but there's a portable version of [XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp).

You wouldn't necessarily have to use the Apache portion.  The app could just run from the command-line, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to use PHP as standalone programming language, I mean without using a web server and a browser.i can answer your other question.

**SQLite is a database system**(to be more specific: a library!) which provides you all the basic capabilities of **SQL database without needing to install any specific database servers**.But you do need to copy a small .dll file(sqlite3.dll i suppose) into your working dirctory.The file is only a very small one,but you get all of the basic capabilities of a database such as INSERT DELETE UPDATE SELECT etc..Its a great light weight database..i mean it..really lightweight.

also PHP has inbuilt support for SQLite database.so compatibility will never be a problem

Have a look at their home page https://sqlite.org/

This is what they describe themselves:**SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world.**

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [phpdesktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) that gives you:

- Embedded web browser based on Chromium framework let you benefits from HTML5, javascript and jQuery.
- Embedded web server with mongoose let you use php.
- embedded database engine with SQLite.